# Fetching information from another UI

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

There is a UI application which provided multiple functionality out of which one is downloading customer info. Only authenticated users are allowed to access the application functionlity.

I am building a UI using JSF which needs to pull the customer info from the UI that I had mentioned above. A button download customers will be present in my UI. On clicking download customers , my UI has to call the other UI , enter user id and password (configured in property file in my UI) and then send approperiate request to download the customer information and finally display that information to the user.

UI Application 1 -

(1) Click on Get Customer Info Menu Link - triggers the below listed activities in background

UI Application 2 - 
                     (a) Login 
                     (b) Click on Customer Info Menu Link
                     (c) Click on downlod customer data button in customer info screen
(2) Display customer info to user.

Activities (a) , (b) and (c) have to done in the background transparent to the user and info from (c) must be displayed to user.

Is this possible? Is there any framwork / tools which would make the task of pulling info from another UI easier.

Regards,

Comment: You mean you have two separate applications and one needs to access the `UI` of the other?

Answer (score 1):

Do not view them as two different "UI"s. They are two different systems. What you are trying to achieve is system level integration. Most systems support some kind of "programmatic" service layer. First explore if it has one. If it does not, explore if you could build and use. If that is not possible, check if you can bring both systems under the same login, namely, Single Sign-On applications.

Comment: Hi Srini, the option that you had put forth is our preferred solution as well and it makes the job much easier and solution very elegant. However there is no api that is currently exposed and also since the system that we are trying to use will not be modified to expose a new api , neither will database be opened to us - this is the constraint that we have. Also , I was specifying the system in terms of UI to explain the complexity. We are just trying to do a feasibility study as to whether this can be achieved at least as a "tactical" solution for now.

Comment: Well, you can always open an [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) to do this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have username and password saved in a property file:

You can easily do the following:

you just call the servlet by assigning the action and `onsubmit` `url` to that servlet `URL` adding the username and password and any other properties.
And when on response you just neatly present it to the user in your `UI`.

Comment: Hi Mike, I would have to perform multiple activities , everything in background. I have edited the info in my original post.